# Bash function hangs while command run perfectly without function

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, shell, shell-scripting

Following function hangs :

```
ssh() {
    local RESULTS;
    RESULTS=$(ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $SSH_COMMAND1);
    echo $RESULTS;
}

ssh;
```

while if i run following commands they work fine :

```
    RESULTS=$(ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $SSH_COMMAND1);
    echo $RESULTS;
```

Can someone please guide me to the right direction of looking for error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a recursive error. You define a function called 'ssh' then call the same function in your function. This results in a recursive loop.

Specify the absolute path to the `ssh` binary and that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I named the function same as the command :P

Answer (score 0):

I just made the same mistake. I think you can also use the `command` command to run a command (the binary itself) that has the same name as the function, in order to avoid hardcoding the path to the binary:

```
ssh() {
    local RESULTS;
    RESULTS=$(command ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $SSH_COMMAND1);
    echo $RESULTS;
}
```

Though for what you're doing here I do recommend naming the function differently; `ssh` is a very common command that no one would expect to behave this way!